# AWS NodeJS lambda call within a lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda

I've trying to call lambda function from another lambda function and get result to execute rest of the lambda.

Basic flow of function is below

```
X - main lambda function
    - process A (independent)
    - process C (need input from process B)
    - process D
    - return final dataset 
Y - Child lambda function
   - process B ( need input from process A and respond back to X )
```

This is my code so far

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

const GetUserCheckoutData: Handler = async (userRequest: EmptyProjectRequest, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {

    const dboperation = new UserController();
    const usercheckoutdata = new CheckOutInfo();
    const addresscontroller = new  AddressController();
    const ordercontroller = new OrderController();
    const paypalcreateorder = new PayPalController();

    const userid = await dboperation.getUserID(userRequest.invokeemailAddress);

    usercheckoutdata.useraddressdetails = await addresscontroller.GetListOfAddressByUserID(userid);
    var orderlist = new Array<Order>();
    orderlist = [];

    orderlist =  await ordercontroller.GetCurrentOrder(userid);

    console.log("Order Complete");

    var params = {
        FunctionName: 'api-ENGG-SellItem', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'Tail',
        Payload: '{ "orderlist" : xxxxxxx }'
      };

    lambda.invoke(params, (err:any, res:any) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

        callback(null, res.Payload);
    });

    usercheckoutdata.orderID = await paypalcreateorder.CreateOrder(userid , orderlist);
    usercheckoutdata.orderPreview = await ordercontroller.OrderPreview(userid);


    //callback(null,usercheckoutdata);
};

export { GetUserCheckoutData }
```

I tried a few different ways but flow is not working properly. cross lambda function is executing. but cannot get the response on time.

My child lambda function demo code

```
import { Handler, Context } from "aws-lambda";

const SellItem: Handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    console.log("Other Lambda Function");
    setTimeout(() => {

        callback(null, "My name is Jonathan"); 
     }, 1000 * 10); // 10 seconds delay
}

export {SellItem}
```

I think since I don't have much NodeJS knowledge this is happening. don't know how to put call back in right way I guess. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your call to the second lambda a promise, so you can await it.

```
    const res = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();

    // do things with the response
```

Comment: thanks. but it giving me below error             ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames

Comment: 504 OK","error":{"errorMessage":"2020-02-07T20:44:42.421Z d4d05a74-fd9b-42a2-9d60-ffb3f04ba8a2 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"

Comment: any way after i change 10 sec to 5 sec it start working. thanks.